# Hibernate still looking for setter despite access="field" in Hibernate Mappings file

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting the following error:

```
PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property firstName in class com.example.SpecialUser
```

Despite having 'default-access' AND 'access' set to 'field' in my SpecialUser.hbm.xml file:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.example" default-cascade="all" default-access="field">
<joined-subclass extends="User" name="com.example.SpecialUser" table="special_user" lazy="false">
    <key column="user_id"/>
    <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="java.lang.String" access="field" />
</joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The SpecialUser class:

```
public class SpecialUser extends User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 101162430966683621L;

    private String firstName;

    public SpecialUser() {
        super();
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

}
```

The User Hibernate Mappings file:

```
<class name="User" table="user" lazy="false">
    <id name="userId" column="user_id" type="java.lang.String">
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id> 

    <property name="password" column="password" type="java.lang.String" />
</class>
```

Comment: Can you post the class `SpecialUser` with all getter and setter methods?

Comment: Where's setter method in your class updated?

Comment: For entity property mapping, basically you need a pair of getter and setter for it. I can see only getter method for your `firstName` property. But not found the method like `setFirstName()`.

Comment: @suninsky op wants fie
ld access. not setteer access.

Comment: Could you please share the User class config?

Comment: I think there is one solution using annotation is : @Transient public String getFirstName()

Comment: @KevalTrivedi I unfortunately can't use annotations in this project

Comment: Could you try with field access on the `User` class? Just to find out if the User entity setting is inherited in the `SpecialUser`.

Comment: @Rohit Already tried that, didn't make any difference

Comment: Are you sure Your database filed name are proper mapping ?

Comment: @KevalTrivedi Everything else should be fine - this has been working with the setter method in place, now I'm trying to remove it and make the object immutable

Comment: How do you run this code standalone java or in JEE container? Did you ensure your build was sucessful and latest configuration is used is runs?

Comment: Standalone Java. Yes, the build was successful and yes, I pried open the .jar file to check the correct config was present

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: Where is the Setter in you model?

Comment: @JorgeCampos 3.3.1.GA but I've also tried upgrading to 3.6.10.Final as part of my testing.

Comment: @OomphFortuity Please read the question

Comment: @ThomShutt Have you tried to put the `joined-subclass` tags inside the `class` tag of your User object? Like `<class name="User"...> ... <joined-subclass name="SpecialUser" ... > ... </joined-subclass></class>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having this problem in a larger project, I suggest that you create a stripped project that only has the base configuration required to persist your entity and go from there. At a glance, the only thing that looks odd about your configuration is that the User class doesn't have a package declaration.

In all tests, I moved the User class into the com.example package and modified the *.hbm.xml files to match that change.

**Test 1**

- Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
- Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE [LocalSessionFactoryBean]
- context.xml (below)

*Result*: Compiled and ran a simple persistence test.

**Test 2**

- Hibernate 3.6.10.Final.
- hibernate.cfg.xml (below)

*Result*: Compiled and ran a simple persistence test.

**Test 3**

- Hibernate 3.3.1.GA.
- hibernate.cfg.xml (below)

*Result*: Compiled and ran a simple persistence test.

Could you please perform a similar test outside of your project? If you are able to reproduce the error, supply the information required to reproduce that small test.

Full code below for comparison.

---

User.java

```
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7240509760819729807L;

    private String userId;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

User.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.example.User" table="user" lazy="false">
        <id name="userId" column="user_id" type="java.lang.String">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="password" column="password" type="java.lang.String" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

SpecialUser.java

```
package com.example;

public class SpecialUser extends User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 101162430966683621L;

    private String firstName;

    public SpecialUser() {
        super();
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
}
```

SpecialUser.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.example" default-cascade="all" >
    <joined-subclass extends="com.example.User" name="com.example.SpecialUser" table="special_user" lazy="false">
        <key column="user_id" />
        <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="java.lang.String" access="field" />
    </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>       
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <mapping resource="model/User.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="model/SpecialUser.hbm.xml" /> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" primary="true" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>model/SpecialUser.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>model/User.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
         </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

Comment: Ended up being a stupid mistake, in some instances a slightly different version of User.hbm.xml was being pulled in.

Comment: Marking this answer as the solution, as it led me to the problem.